# USB 3.0 and 3.1 are recognized as 2.0

Tags: 18.04, usb

I have desktop with ASUS PRIME X370-PRO motherboard and according tech-specs  all of USB ports are 3.0 or 3.1, there are no 2.0 ports.
Problem is that all exposed USB ports are recognized as 2.0. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Bus 003 should be 3.1 all others 3.0. I connect 3.0 device and bet only 2.0 speeds.
[image]

Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
# lsusb
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 24ae:2010  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1b1c:0c04 Corsair 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=88XXau, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/14p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M

# lspci | grep -i usb
02:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43b9 (rev 02)
07:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1143 USB 3.1 Host Controller
0b:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) USB 3.0 Host Controller

# uname -r
5.0.0-23-generic
```

Comment: There is nothing to fix. All ports are managed by `xhci_hcd`. All looks OK.

Comment: So why do I see 480M on Bus 03? It is a 3.0 device connected to 3.1 port.

Comment: RTL8812AU is unlikely to be 3.0. You can look into `dmesg` and see.

Comment: This is a driver issue. The installed driver doesn't support USB 3.0 yet.

Comment: [ 4034.414246] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
[ 4036.890138] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 4037.106514] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8812, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 4037.106517] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4037.106518] usb 3-1: Product: 802.11n NIC
[ 4037.106520] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 4037.106521] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 123456
[ 4037.222290] usb 3-1: 88XXau 00:c0:ca:a5:78:93 hw_info[d7]

Comment: See `high-speed`?

Comment: You mean USB driver or RTL8812AU?

Comment: Exactly. That driver. All is OK with your ports. If you test with some other 3.0 device, all should be OK. But really 480M is enough for a wireless device. You won't get more anyway.

Comment: It is https://www.alfa.com.tw/products_detail/1.htm. This adapter is 3.0 and should be capable for more that 480M so I think it should work on 3.0 mode 5000M. My ISP can reach 300Mbps but right now I only getting up to 100Mbps. Thats why I am looking what is wrong. On Windows 10 this device performs as expected.

Comment: Linux support of Realtek wireless devices is limited, that's the problem. 300 M is reasonable, but this 1200M is a "marketing" speed. You can find real speeds in the net.

Comment: @Pilot6 plz see my answer and see if it makes sense...

Comment: I saw it, but I have no idea if this work.

Comment: @Pilot6 OP has confirmed that my answer works. note: I made minor edits to the .conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove any rtl8812au drivers that you may have installed, and try this driver...

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

You should create a file in `/etc/modprobe.d` called `88XXau.conf` that looks similar to this, to force USB 3.x operation. Without this file, the driver is **supposed** to come up and start in USB 2.x mode and switch up...

```
# Initially it will use USB2.0 mode, which will limit 5G 11ac throughput
# (USB2.0 bandwidth only 480Mbps => throughput around 240Mbps)
# with modprobe options it will switch to USB3.0 mode at initial driver load
#
options 88XXau rtw_switch_usb_mode=1
#
#
#
### TODO: run time change usb2.0/3.0 mode
#
### usb2.0 => usb3.0
#
# sudo sh -c "echo '1' > /sys/module/88XXau/parameters/rtw_switch_usb_mode"
#
### usb3.0 => usb2.0
#
# sudo sh -c "echo '2' > /sys/module/88XXau/parameters/rtw_switch_usb_mode"
```

Comment: worked like a charm :)
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=88XXau, 5000M

Answer (score 1):

All ports are properly detected. Linux kernel adds both 2.0 and 3.0 hubs to USB.

So you have three 2.0 and three 3.0 hubs.

It this case the problem is that the RTL8812AU device is detected as USB 2.0 device because of the driver limitation.

But real transfer speed of a wireless device is unlikely to be more than 480M. So it doesn't look like a real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Crazy suggestion: check your cable.  Some seemingly high-quality cables won't negotiate gbps speeds and so everything ends up at 480mbps of USB2.  When this happens, in `lsusb` it will land under the USB 2 controller, and the device will be listed as usb2 / 480m.  It's normal/standard for the XHCI driver to expose both a USB 2 hub and a USB 3 hub in lsusb, and then devices appear under whichever is appropriate for their speed.

Comment: This was an issue with my SSD enclosure. Old USB cables or so called "charge cables" do not have enough wires in them to carry more data and produce high speeds.